# Angular with typescript: How to display Html Raw?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

[image]

Help me display data with angular 2. Im used [innerHtml] but display like image

```
<div id="decode-html" [innerHTML]="Detail">

</div>
```

My string Detail

```
&lt;p&gt;Tập 7 &amp;quot;Bước nhảy ng&amp;agrave;n c&amp;acirc;n&amp;quot; sẽ l&amp;ecirc;n s&amp;oacute;ng VTV3 v&amp;agrave;o l&amp;uacute;c 21h15 Chủ nhật 16/10/2016.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see anything related to typescript or angular here. Your problem is not understanding regular HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify innerHTML from HTML. `.innerHTML` is a JavaScript property.
You need HTML:

```
<div id="decode-html">

</div>
```

Then you need JavaScript:

```
var detail="the string you want to insert";
document.getElementById("decode-html").innerHTML=detail;
```

If you're trying to use typescript in Angular and you don't yet know HTML, you've got a loooong way to go...